# Как создать плиточную структуру html блока на flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Стандартно при `space-between` получается такое расположение элементов. Последний элемент располагается всегда справа. Если в последней строке 3 элемента, то между ними согласно space-between также равное расстояние, но оно отличается от расстояния которое между блоками выше строкой.

[image: Стандартно при space-between]

Как можно сделать вот такой вид с помощью `flexbox`? Мне всё также нужно сделать равное расстояние между блоками (т.к. я незнаю заранее ширину контейнера/ширину экрана), незнаю кол-во блоков которое будет, знаю только размер этих блоков (по ширине их может влазить то 2, то 3, то 4 шт.).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. идут блоки к примеру по 4 шт в ряд и между ними такое-то расстояние, как сделать так, чтобы в последней строке, если блоков не 4 шт. то расстояние между ними всё равно было такое-же, как в рядах выше?

Comment: Добавьте свой код сюда

Answer (score 1):

```css
.column {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.BigBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>



<body>
  <div class="BigBlock">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">

      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">

      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `flex-basis` для разделения на блоки.

### Пример `flex-basis` с разметкой

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для маленьких разрешений используй `media`-запрос для создания адаптивности, если она нужна.

### Использование `Grid`ов

А вообще я бы рекомендовал использовать `grid` для создания подобного рода разметки, потому что это более гибкое и удобное решение.

Например вы можете задать сколько нужно вам элементов в строке grid-template-`columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` и какие зазоры вам нужны `grid-gap: 10px`, чего вы не сможете сделать на `flexbox` или сможете но не так просто.

### Пример c `Grid`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```